# ArcMap 'in_memory' trouble?

Tags: arcpy, in-memory, error-000582

Being new to ArcMap, and ArcPy I have a problem with a script including several geoprocessing functions.
The number of functions inspired a search for a means to save outputs (subsequent inputs) to memory, leading to the 'in_memory' assist provided by ArcMap.

However the following script errors out at the RasterToPolygon_Conversion() and I am unsure why...

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Important\\testMap.mxd"

DEM_raster_layer = "C:\\canyon.tif"
Camera_point_layer = "C:\\birdsEye.shp"

# Process: Visibility analysis
arcpy.gp.Visibility_sa(DEM_raster_layer, Camera_point_layer, "in_memory\\0", "",\
                      "FREQUENCY", "NODATA", "0.00001201","FLAT_EARTH", "0.13", "", "",\
                      "OFFSETA", "", "", "AZIMUTH1", "AZIMUTH2", "VERT1", "VERT2")

# Process: Visibilty boundries cleanup
arcpy.gp.BoundaryClean_sa("in_memory\\0", "in_memory\\1", "ASCEND", "TWO_WAY")
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\0")

# Process: Visibility raster to polygon(s)
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion("in_memory\\1", "in_memory\\2", "NO_SIMPLIFY", "")
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\1")
```

Here is the following error return:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 32, in    File "c:\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 244, in RasterToPolygon     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.

Im guessing there is some syntax or logic mistake in this method?

Comment: Have you tried running `RasterToPolygon_Conversion()` with output to an `in_memory` dataset in the ArcMap GUI? Some geoprocessing tools (e.g. project) don't allow outputting to `in_memory` datasets.

Comment: @dmahr : Successful manual output of 'in_memory'  in the ArcMap GUI.  I'm wondering if its the previous 'in_memory' input...

Answer (score 3):

Well, after helpful advice from 'dmahr' I manually tested this process in the ArcMap GUI and it worked successfully.  That drew on the conclusion that possibly a naming issue was at fault.

Indeed such seemed to be the case.  After using a text+numeric name, the processing worked without troubles.

The following ad hoc changes temporarily resolved the problem:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Important\\testMap.mxd"

DEM_raster_layer = "C:\\canyon.tif"
Camera_point_layer = "C:\\birdsEye.shp"

# Process: Visibility analysis
arcpy.gp.Visibility_sa(DEM_raster_layer, Camera_point_layer, "in_memory\\something1", "", "FREQUENCY", "NODATA", "0.00001201", \
                             "FLAT_EARTH", "0.13", "", "", "OFFSETA", "", "", "AZIMUTH1", "AZIMUTH2", "VERT1", "VERT2")

# Process: Visibilty boundries cleanup
arcpy.gp.BoundaryClean_sa("in_memory\\something1", "in_memory\\something2", "ASCEND", "TWO_WAY")
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\something1")

# Process: Visibility raster to polygon(s)
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion("in_memory\\something2", "in_memory\\something3", "NO_SIMPLIFY", "")
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\something2")
```

Comment: Good detective work. This is probably because `in_memory` datasets are treated like geodatabase feature classes, which (I now remember) cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Great future reference.

Comment: Have a look at the `ValidateTableName` function, it can be used to watch for these sorts of cases. For example, `arcpy.ValidateTableName('1', 'in_memory')` returns `'T1'`.